# Getting the correct subtotal DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need help with summarizing the correct totals. If I just multiply the two numbers together, I get the correct individual total but not grand total.

However, if I try to iterate using sumx and summarize, the values from the PY are excluded due to what I believe are the filters for only the current year.

How do I iterate and get the missing values to appear properly?

Formula without iterators:

```
Component Diff = 
[CY fg all lvl3] * [Ratio Difference]
```

[Correct line items- incorrect total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCPNn.png)

[Semi-correct total, missing line items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1xeC.png)

[Link to pbix file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R-dIg6TEBZjEHREOmL1nSg0Lz-p1cDVk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Really not clear. Please provide simple and clear examples of the problem, then show us the expected result.